# Ошибка Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: "invalid syntax" в IronPython

Tags: c#, python-3.x, ironpython

Мне надо связать код Python с C#, делаю через IronPython3 и соответственно Python3. Версия .NET 7. Все необходимые библиотеки из NuGet установлены

Вот мой код:

```cs
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib");
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
scope.SetVariable("pop", "Что?");
engine.ExecuteFile(@"main.py", scope); // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
```

Код из main.py полностью рабочий

Скриншот исключения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Python какой версии установлен?

Comment: Установлен Python 3.11

Comment: IronPython поддерживает только 2.7 и 3.4 версии.

Comment: То есть IronPython 3.7 поддерживает только Python 3.4?

Comment: Не знаю откуда вы 3.7 версию нашли. На официальном сайте https://ironpython.net/ только 3.4. Хотя, не исключаю что переехали в другое место.

Comment: А, ой я ошибся...

Comment: Спасибо! Я перепишу пайтон код на более старую версию Python